# how to have accessible variables in component methods

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sinch

I'm working on a component that takes care of registering my users to Sinch (voip platform). In order for my registration to work I need to have some variables that are accessible throughout my component methods. I'm wondering how this should be done using vue.

I need my variable `sinchClient` to be accessible in my methods `newUserRequest()` and `loginRequest()`

Any tips?

**Sinch variable**

```
var sinchClient = new SinchClient({
  applicationKey: "My-Key",
  capabilities: {
    messaging: true,
    calling: true
  },
  supportActiveConnection: true,
  onLogMessage: function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
  }
});
```

**Methods**

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      username: null,
      name: null,
      password: null,
      loggedIn: false
    };
  },
  mounted() {},
  methods: {
    newUserRequest() {
      console.log(this.name, this.password);

      if (this.name && this.password) {
        var handleSuccess = () => {
          console.log("User created");
          this.loggedIn = true;
          this.name = sinchClient.user.userId;
        };
        var handleFail = error => {
          console.log(error.message);
        };

        var signUpObject = { username: this.name, password: this.password };
        sinchClient
          .newUser(signUpObject)
          .then(sinchClient.start.bind(sinchClient))
          .then(() => {
            localStorage[
              "sinchSession-" + sinchClient.applicationKey
            ] = JSON.stringify(sinchClient.getSession());
          })
          .then(handleSuccess)
          .fail(handleFail);
      }
    },
    logInRequest() {
      if (this.name && this.password) {
        var handleSuccess = () => {
          console.log("User logged in");
          this.loggedIn = true;
          this.name = sinchClient.user.userId;
        };
        var handleFail = error => {
          console.log(error.message);
        };
        var signUpObject = { username: this.name, password: this.password };
        sinchClient
          .start(signUpObject)
          .then(() => {
            localStorage[
              "sinchSession-" + sinchClient.applicationKey
            ] = JSON.stringify(sinchClient.getSession());
          })
          .then(handleSuccess)
          .fail(handleFail);
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Define it in a module and `import` it

Comment: Able to give me an example to get me started quickly?

Comment: Have you used `import` or `require` before?

Comment: I have used import before within a react application. First time doing this with vue

Comment: Different build systems differ in particulars, but you should be able to make a module that defines your variable and then import (or require) that module in any other module that needs it.

Comment: you should really use authtickets on your server no register via javascript its not secure only for demo purposes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define `sinchClient` globally and access it using window (`window.sinchClient`). Better you can create a Vue plugin and inject it in the app context:

```
var sinchClient = new SinchClient({
  applicationKey: "My-Key",
  capabilities: {
    messaging: true,
    calling: true
  },
  supportActiveConnection: true,
  onLogMessage: function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
  }
})
Vue.use({
  install: function(Vue) {
    Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$sinchClient', {
      get () { return sinchClient }
    })
  }
})
```

And access it with `this.$sinchClient`in Vue context

Comment: Where do I define this exactly?

Comment: I don't know the structure of your application. The better way for me, is to create a vue-sinch-client.js file in a plugins folder, and import the plugin before the initialisation of your app.